# Changing running program behavior with shell commands

Tags: python, linux, shell

I'm writing a wallpaper manager in Python. I'm targeting this project for Linux and want to make the script easy to slip into autostart files (such as .xinitrc, et. al.). I'm hoping to implement a host of functionality that can be generated by typing commands such as...

```
<wallpaper_manager_program> --reject (load new wallpaper, delete previously displayed)
<wallpaper_manager_program> --next-image
<wallpaper_manager_program> --prev-image
<wallpaper_manager_program> --randomize-image
<wallpaper_manager_program> --change [specific-image-file]
<wallpaper_manager_program> --update (pull down new wallpapers from a chosen url)
```

and so on from the shell while the program is already running. Users could wrap the various command with whatever keybinding tool they'd prefer (e.g. xbindkeys, Unity, etc.). Which is the most appropriate IPC method for my problem? In a nutshell I would like:

- Room for future functionality as time goes on
- Security (e.g. so that people's images don't get accidentally deleted or overwritten by someone mucking with a config file that's being read)
- Lightweight (without hogging system resources as the program is a background manager afterall; not a fancy windows manager...)
- Responsive (so that if someone issues the reject command, the command will be completed immediately instead of the next iteration of routine calls)

I am not terribly concerned with how much work has to go into getting the applications to intercommunicate, but obviously would prefer the less cumbersome approach as the program isn't storing any vital data about individuals or doing anything incredibly important (well, that depends on how you regard your background images...)

*As a clarification*: I'm not asking about calling shell commands from a Python script but rather how to change my scripts behavior from the shell.

**Edit:** 
When originally asking, I did not know about IPC in general and so have refined parts of the question to reflect a (hopefully) more specific inquisition about which IPC approach would be best for this project.

Comment: Could you load settings for the wallpaper from a config file before each reloading the wallpaper action. Users could then alter the config and it would be picked up by the script before it loads the new wallpaper.

Comment: I thought about having a 'reject' option checked at every interval in a config file, however, this meant you'd need to make sure there's no needless deleting of people's wallpapers on accident (or maliciously) and it wouldn't be immediate (at least from what I'd think about implementing it: having your primary functions on a sleep delay and then checking that file).

Comment: How complicated is the information you want to send to the wallpaper manager? Do you need it to be able to process a whole bunch of different commands sent to it from the shell, or does it just need to respond to a simple `--reject` command?

Comment: It would be nice to scale the program's functionality with other commands such as adding images, requesting the current background's file name, etc. Then the functions could be accessed via the shell or bound to specific keys (go to next image, go to last, randomize, change, etc.)

Comment: Ok. Then you need more than just a simple signal. Communicating via a [named pipe](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Named_pipe) is probably the easiest to implement, since it can be done with normal file read & write functions. The other options aren't that hard to do, but will require you to do a bit more learning. Explaining how to do all this stuff is probably a bit broad for Stackoverflow. So do a little research & try writing a pair of simple programs that communicate via a named pipe. And if you get stuck, post your code in a new question.

Comment: @PM2Ring Updated the question, hopefully its less broad now? Want to make sure it's concise enough. Thanks for the insight!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This is essentially a question about inter-process-communication - and the answers vary massively depending on your goals.

On way to accomplish this is to write a PID-file containing the PID of your wallpaper-display-app to a well-known location. Then the manager can look this PID up, and send a signal (e.g. signal.SIGUSR1) to the running process. In there, all you need is a signal-handler to trigger the desired behaviour.

Other options are HTTP on a well-known port, named pipes, DBUS etc.

HTTP is the simplest one: just use the built-in SimpleHTTPServer or wsgiref to launch a web-app on a non-privileged port. Listen on incoming requests, and react accordingly.

The downside of this is the allocation of a system-resource (the port) that possibly causes conflicts and security issues.

Named pipes avoid this, by using a well-known endpoint e.g. /tmp/wallpaper-saver-fifo as filename, you can have manager and background process communicate. I think I would go for this, recipes can be found all over the net, e.g. here http://www.roman10.net/named-pipe-in-linux-with-a-python-example/

A way to use these without the nitty gritty details could be nanomsg, which has python-bindings and makes these things very easy.

DBUS is a system-wide IPC mechanism used by other applications already. I have only dabbled with it - it's not really hard, but because it cares more about security, it can be a bit cumbersome and depending on your actual use-case is maybe a bit over the top.

Comment: Thanks for your answer, it's helped a lot. Kind of green to IPC in general so didn't think of that being an answer (or its options). I think in regards to my question DBUS does seem kind of like overkill, and signals seem kind of finite, so I'll probably go with named pipes.

Answer (score 1):

You have some options to do [IPC](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Inter-process_communication):

- open a port on localhost (will allow all users to access it)
- open a UNIX socket (That's like a file with permissions)
- if it a simple signal, use [signal](https://docs.python.org/2/library/signal.html).